# Программа на C не читает кириллицу

Tags: c, строки, codeblocks

При работе со строками у меня было задание подсчитать количество символов, 
которые не являются кириллицей и каждую маленькую гласную букву заменить на 
большую. Вот код, который я составил:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 10
int main()
{
char str[N];
int j=0;
printf("Enter text:");
gets(str);
for(int k=0;*(str+k)!='\0';k++)
{   
if(isalnum(*(str+k))||(*(str+k)>=33&&*(str+k)<=126))// от 33 до 126 это 
        //проверка на символы и знаки(они преобразоваются в такой код)
        j=j+1;
        //количество символов не являющихся кириллицей
        else if(*(str+k)=='а'||*(str+k)=='о'||*(str+k)=='и'||* 
        (str+k)=='е'||*(str+k)=='ё'||*(str+k)=='э'||*(str+k)=='ы'||* 
        (str+k)=='у'||* (str+k)=='ю'||*(str+k)=='я')
        {
            if(islower(*(str+k)))
           *(str+k)=toupper(*(str+k));
                 else
                 *(str+k)=tolower(*(str+k));
        }
}
printf("Takih simvolov %d\n",j);
   printf("%s",str);

return 0;
}

И я заметил еще, что условие `else if(*(str+k)=='а' и т.д.)` никогда не 
сбывается, даже если я ввожу букву указанную в условии. Операционная система 
у меня Windows 8.
```

Comment: Укажите хотя бы ОС какая? Еще лучше, какую кодировку используете

Comment: Сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Из-за проблем с кодировкой кириллический символ занимает не 1, а 2 байта.

Comment: Наверняка литералы в utf-8, а консоль в cp866.

Comment: Я кое что изменил в коде. Подключил библиотеку #include <Windows.h> и написал SetConsoleCP(1251);SetConsoleOutputCP(1251), а также сменил шрифт в консоли на  Lucida Console. Теперь у меня правильно считывает кириллицу, но функции строк не работают:(

Comment: В Windows при работе с консолью (да и во многих других случаях) следует использовать `wchar_t`  @SergeyGornostaev а литералы не могут быть в utf-8 (точнее utf-8 символы не помещаются в `char`)

Comment: Для начала введите русскую буковку и распечатайте ее код (десятичное число), а рядом распечатайте код той же буквы из программы (т.е. литерала)

Comment: @avp У меня один и тот же код получается...

Comment: Тогда по шагам сравнений идите, что именно не работает.

Comment: @VTT из справки GCC по ключам `finput-charset` и `fexec-charset`: _The default is UTF-8._

Comment: Я скорее всего понял в чем проблема, функции tolower и toupper не работают с кириллицей.